# Converting Json attribute name to entity property name in a Spring MVC GET request

Tags: json, neo4j, jackson, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

Hi I have an application which is using SpringDataNeo4j , Spring MVC ...
I have the following classes as examples. One is the entity and the other is the JSON object.

```
@NodeEntity(label="MyBean")
public class MyBean() {

    @Property(name = "my_name")
    String my_name;
    @Property(name = "last_modified_by")
    String last_modified_by;

    //setter & getters
}
```

.

```
@JsonRootName("myBean")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class MyBeanData {

    String myName;
    String lastModifiedBy;

    //setter getters
}
```

This is the request handler in my spring mvc controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<MyBeanData> getMyBeans(@RequestParam(name = "sortDir", required = false) String sortDir,
        @RequestParam(name = "sortProp", required = false) String sortProp){

    //execute the Custom query to get all mybeans sorted by sortProp
}
```

Now my problem is that the property names used in "sortProp" are the json object attribute names for example "lastModifiedBy"... The sort query does not work with json attribute names it works only if I use entity property names . Is there an easy & clean way to convert a single json attribute NAME to the corresponding entity property NAME before executing the query ?like annotations ?? I do not want to add a converter method like the one below in the entity with so many if elses .

```
public String converter(String sortProp){
    if("lastModifiedBy".equals(sortPro)){
        return "last_modified_by"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use many if/elses even if you want to repeatedly compare strings, you can switch on strings:

```
 switch (sortPro) {
     case "lastModifiedBy": return "last_modified_by";
     // ...
 }
```

However, the simplest way to store the mapping and do the conversion is to use a `Map<String, String>`:

```
private static final Map<String, String> SORT_FIELD_MAP;

static {
    Map<String, String> sortFieldMap = new HashMap<>();
    sortFieldMap.put("lastModifiedBy", "last_modified_by");
    // ...
    SORT_FIELD_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(sortFieldMap);
}

public String converter(String sortProp) {
    return SORT_FIELD_MAP.get(sortProp);
}
```

(Or use immutable collections from Guava or equivalent)

Comment: Is there any way to use the Jackson for this ? just curious ... I already have the entity & the json objects .. so I was thinking maybe we have a solution already implemented. I have so many classes so I do not really want to go over all of the classes and add the converter...

Comment: I don't see how, Jackson does not concern itself with mapping the DTO to an entity. You could however, develop your own solution to register the mappings, using your own set of annotations: annotate the fields of the DTOs, register the classes with the conversion service which will introspect them and store the mappings per class (a map of maps), then just call the service with the class and the name of the sorting property. I'm not aware of a solution already doing this.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. I will use the implementation you suggested

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer just as an alternative implementation for what Frank suggested .

So here are the steps I do : 
Using the  [Reflection library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) here  , I created a map of  where :

- Key is --> the name of all the fields Annotated with @Property
- Value is -->  the property value of all @Property s

BeanPackage is the package path of classes we want to scan.

```
 @PostConstruct
private void init() {
    List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<ClassLoader>();
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .setScanners(
                    new SubTypesScanner(false /* don't exclude Object.class */),
                    new ResourcesScanner(),
                    new FieldAnnotationsScanner())
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[0])))
            .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix(beanPackage))));

    Set<Field> fields = reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(Property.class);
     fields.forEach(field -> jsonToEntityMap.put(field.getName(), field.getAnnotation(Property.class).name()));
```

Comment: Since you have a single `Map<String, String>`, make sure you don't have collisions between classes. Otherwise, you could use a `Map<Class, Map<String, String>>`, a `Map<Pair<Class, String>, String>` or a Guava `Table<Class, String, String>`.

Comment: I do not have a collision , the property name is always the lowered case separated by '_' version of json attribute. So even in case of duplications , they will have the correct mapping.But you are right , in case of collision , your option is the solution.